# How to handle REQUEST in PHP

Tags: php, httpwebrequest, rpc

is there a class to handle `$_REQUEST` that makes the life of a php developer easier?
I want to handle the client requests easier.
I dont  want to test with `if(is_set($_REQUEST['blabla'])) {makesomthing();}`
I wish there could be a solution like this.

```
class rpclike
{
 public function getMember()
 {
  $memberid = $this->inputhandler['memberid'];
  $member = $this->memberclass->getmember($memberid);

   foreach($member as $mem)
   {
    echo $mem->id;
   }
 }

}

$rpc = new rpclike();
```

then if i call the rpclike from a javascript like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="GETURL("rpclike.php?getMember&memberid=22")">Get member</a>
```

Which class can do something like that?

Comment: Allowing the users to decide what will be called will always end in disaster.

Comment: i realy cant understand why the question is getting down voted, its a normal question. I think There is no reason to down vote

Comment: I don't like it because its prone to security problems. Any function you put in that class is going to be exposed to the web. You might be the lone developer for your project but someone else may see this and think it's a good idea, implement it and someone working on their project might not know the exposure and implement a delete_user method or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't really have a default class structure that you can utilize in that kind of manner, as it's origins are in procedural-based programming.

It would be fairly trivial for you to create a class like that if you felt the need for it.  However, you would really just be adding overhead.  If the convenience of it is worth it for you, then you could utilize the [__get() and __set()](http://php.net/__get) methods to handle existence checks for you.

The fact that you want to use this for handling client requests in an easier fashion is probably a good indicator that you should move to something like an MVC framework, which usually handle URLs and route them to appropriate methods for you automatically.  Most PHP frameworks will do this for you already.  For a nice overview on how the process commonly works, you could [see how CodeIgniter does it](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

Comment: thank you, you motivated me to use from now and the most time just the framewort codelgniter, have a nice evening

Answer (score 2):

It's not recommended that you use `$_REQUEST` as it poses security concerns.  You should be using one of `$_GET`, `$_POST`, or `$_COOKIE` depending on what global request var you are trying to retrieve.  Your best bet would be to have something like the following:

```
class input {

    public static function get($key, $value = false) {
        return (!empty($_GET[$key])) ? $_GET[$key] : $value;
    }

    public static function post($key, $value = false) {
        return (!empty($_POST[$key])) ? $_POST[$key] : $value;
    }

    public static function cookie($key, $value = false) {
        return (!empty($_COOKIE[$key])) ? $_COOKIE[$key] : $value;
    }

}
```

You could then use the class like:

```
if (input::post('field', null) != null) {

}
```

or

```
if (input::get('field', false) != false) {

}
```

Although this still requires testing, you can explicitly set the return values in the event no data was set for the global variable.

Comment: Don't forget to implement a `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` workaround.

Comment: Very true, thought about mentioning it... I'm just so used to having it turned off myself.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious security risks involved in this, it is feasible.  It's a common pattern to use for steering requests in an MVC system.

Say you request index.php?class=User&method=ViewProfile

```
$module = new $_GET['class']();
if(!method_exists($module,$_GET['method']))
$module->$eventName();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Being able to invoke an arbitrary method would be a massive security hole.

Comment: sure but first i would call before doing anything if(!$this->user->isadmin())
 return false;

Comment: That's not necessarily the point. Assuming your system isn't secure (no system is 100% secure) and someone managed to spoof the admin credentials, they could potentially perform any operation. If you do your own dispatch you can at least limit this.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like:

```
url: /foo/bar?req=getMembers&memberid=22
```

Then you can do:

```
$request = $_GET['req'];
$request();
```

Slightly less dangerous version:

```
$req_methods = array(
    getMembers => 'some_function',
    saveMembers => 'another_function',
    sendMessage => 'send_him_an_email'
);
$request = $_GET['req'];
$req_methods[$request]();
```

Comment: That seems just a little risky.  E.g., what if someone requests something like /foo/bar?req=apache_child_terminate or some other dangerous function?

Comment: added slightly less dangerous version.

Comment: i would still suggest wrapping the latter with `isset($req_methods[$request])`